# mysql query all sub-accounts and their sub-accounts and so on

Tags: mysql

I have one table like this

```
account_id (INT)
inviter_id (INT)
```

Now,  logged in user with account id 5 wants to see the logs that related to all of his invitees, directly and indirectly, as this table may represent nested hierarchy of unlimited depth.

How would I do that with MySQL?
I accept a solution in PHP/C/C++/C# (:

Actually I've looked for it here and at google and couldn't find anything for that particular case, as everyone try to have nested menus at their website and ask about it.

I've been thinking about simply querying for all accounts in the database (there are about a few hundreds) and from there simply build a tree, or something, but then again I have to stay synced with the database.
So to stay synced with the database I've thought about querying the COUNT() of the accounts in the table, but, what if I need to change an inviter'd (maybe deleting one)?

Anyway, I could appply the rule of "not changing inviter" - if I'd do that, then COUNT() would work I think - is there any *better* approach to that kind of issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this out, this might give you some ideas: http://www.ideashower.com/our_solutions/create-a-parent-child-array-structure-in-one-pass/

Comment: Hi thanks, although it's about building a list... I'm more into a SQL query which will achieve that, because querying the whole table simply doesn't sound right to me.

Answer (score 1):

you can take a look at my answer(s) here if you like:

[Print hierachical data in a parent child form unordered list php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4318010/print-hierachical-data-in-a-parent-child-form-unordered-list-php/4318846#4318846)

or here:

[Mysql Recursive Stored Procedure...Limit 0 reached...can't change the max_sp_recursion_depth variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4056421/mysql-recursive-stored-procedure-limit-0-reached-cant-change-the-max-sp-recu/4056842#4056842)

or here:

[Multi-tiered Comment Replies: Display and Storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4057947/multi-tiered-comment-replies-display-and-storage/4058142#4058142)

or here:

[MySQL Hierarchical Structure Data Extraction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4169535/mysql-hierarchical-structure-data-extraction/4170260#4170260)

hope it helps